# What values do I need in my line object to create window panes for each window?

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my code so far the House class and the NeighborHoodDrive class. I was wondering what values I need in my line object to create window panes for each window in the house? I hope my question is clear and sufficient, I can never seem to ask a question without it getting flagged unfortunately.

House class:

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class House {

    final int BASEWID = 200;
    final int BASEHT = 250;
    final int DOORWID = 40;
    final int DOORHT = 65;
    final int WINHT = 40;
    final int WINWID = 40;

    private Rectangle[] bx = new Rectangle[6]; //base, four windows, doors
    private Line[] ln = new Line[8]; //roof and window cross frames
    private Circle[] cr = new Circle[1]; //doorknob
    private Polygon[] ply = new Polygon[2];
    private Group trGrp = new Group(); //group

    public House(int xOff, int yOff, Pane pane) {
        initHouse();

        setX(xOff);
        setY(yOff);


        pane.getChildren().add(trGrp);
    }


    //Initialize the house components
    public void initHouse() {

        //base of house
        bx[0] = new Rectangle(DOORWID/2, DOORHT+DOORHT/2, BASEWID, BASEHT);
        bx[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[0].setFill(Color.IVORY);

        //door
        bx[1] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+40, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+120, DOORWID, DOORHT);
        bx[1].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[1].setFill(Color.POWDERBLUE);

        //window 1
        bx[2] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID-10, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT-30, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[2].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[2].setFill(Color.LAVENDERBLUSH);

        //window 2
        bx[3] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+90, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT-30, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[3].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[3].setFill(Color.LAVENDER);

        //window 3
        bx[4] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID-10, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+50, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[4].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[4].setFill(Color.LAVENDER);

        //window 4
        bx[5] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+90, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+50, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[5].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[5].setFill(Color.LAVENDERBLUSH);

        //doorknob
        double crX1 = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID / 2.3;
        double crY = bx[0].getY() + BASEHT + BASEWID / -7;
        double crRad = BASEWID / 60;
        cr[0] = new Circle(crX1, crY, crRad);
        cr[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cr[0].setFill(Color.FLORALWHITE);

        //house line
        double midX = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID / 2;
        double leftX = bx[0].getX() - BASEWID / 2;
        double rightX = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID + BASEWID / 2;
        double topY = bx[0].getY() - BASEHT / 2;
        double bottomY = bx[0].getY() + BASEHT / 2;
        ln[0] = new Line(midX, topY, leftX, bottomY);
        ln[1] = new Line(midX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

        //top of house
        ply[0] = new Polygon(ln[0].getStartX(),ln[0].getStartY(),
                bx[0].getX(),bx[0].getY(),
                bx[0].getX()+bx[0].getWidth(),bx[0].getY());
        ply[0].getPoints().addAll();
        ply[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ply[0].setFill(Color.MEDIUMAQUAMARINE);

        //window panes
        ln[2] = new Line(); 


        trGrp.getChildren().addAll(bx[0], bx[1], bx[2], bx[3], bx[4], bx[5], cr[0], ply[0], ln[2]);
    }

    // Get the X Coordinate
    public double getX()
    {
        return trGrp.getLayoutX();
    }

    // Set the X Coordinate
    public void setX(double x)
    {
        trGrp.setLayoutX(x);
    }

    // Get the Y Coordinate
    public double getY()
    {
        return trGrp.getLayoutY();
    }

    // Set the Y Coordinate
    public void setY(double y)
    {
        trGrp.setLayoutY(y);
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class NeighborhoodDrive extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Create a pane to hold the group
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        House house = new House(175, 75 ,pane);

        //Create handler for moving cars
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e ->
        {

        };
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), eventHandler));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play(); // Start animation

        //Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Neighborhood Drive"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code examples seem to be Java, but you tagged your question as JavaScript. Why?

Comment: I got it. I was probably just overthinking it.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why my post is getting down voted? It can't be because there is no research effort literally all of the code is there. If it's unclear someone please explain how.

Comment: _It can't be because there is no research effort literally all of the code is there._ - That is precisely the problem. Just posting all the code you've written does not show your research effort. In fact, it shows the opposite. Research effort is taking the time to try to isolate  and narrow down your problem down. I suggest looking at how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Many times when creating one, you'll discover your problem.

Comment: Could you explain your statement further? I narrowed down my problem to which values I needed in my Line object to create the window panes. I'm not trying create an argument of sorts, I would just like to know how to ask an adequate question on this website without being flagged or down vote.

Comment: Firstly, it seems that in your question description you narrowed down your problem to the code for the line object. So just post the code for the line object. Secondly, as a word of caution. Don't take flags and down-votes personally. If you do, your gonna have a really bad time at Stack Overflow. In this case, you did the right thing; Asking why your question was down-voted, instead of blowing-up. Keep that attitude. Lastly, Address your title. It can be improved. Make your title as to-the-point as possible. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), is a article I recommend reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was just overthinking it. Line line = new line(startX, startY, endX, endY);

```js
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class NeighborhoodDrive extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Create a pane to hold the group
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        House house = new House(175, 75 ,pane);

        //Create handler for moving cars
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e ->
        {

        };
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), eventHandler));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play(); // Start animation

        //Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Neighborhood Drive"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
}
```

```js
 
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class House {

    final int BASEWID = 200;
    final int BASEHT = 250;
    final int DOORWID = 40;
    final int DOORHT = 65;
    final int WINHT = 40;
    final int WINWID = 40;

    private Rectangle[] bx = new Rectangle[6]; //base, four windows, doors
    private Line[] ln = new Line[8]; //roof and window cross frames
    private Circle[] cr = new Circle[1]; //doorknob
    private Polygon[] ply = new Polygon[2];
    private Group trGrp = new Group(); //group

    public House(int xOff, int yOff, Pane pane) {
        initHouse();

        setX(xOff);
        setY(yOff);


        pane.getChildren().add(trGrp);
    }


    //Initialize the house components
    public void initHouse() {

        //base of house
        bx[0] = new Rectangle(DOORWID/2, DOORHT+DOORHT/2, BASEWID, BASEHT);
        bx[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[0].setFill(Color.IVORY);

        //door
        bx[1] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+40, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+120, DOORWID, DOORHT);
        bx[1].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[1].setFill(Color.POWDERBLUE);

        //window 1
        bx[2] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID-10, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT-30, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[2].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[2].setFill(Color.LAVENDERBLUSH);

        //window 2
        bx[3] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+90, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT-30, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[3].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[3].setFill(Color.LAVENDER);

        //window 3
        bx[4] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID-10, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+50, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[4].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[4].setFill(Color.LAVENDER);

        //window 4
        bx[5] = new Rectangle(bx[0].getX()+DOORWID+90, bx[0].getY()+DOORHT+50, WINWID, WINHT);
        bx[5].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bx[5].setFill(Color.LAVENDERBLUSH);

        //doorknob
        double crX1 = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID / 2.3;
        double crY = bx[0].getY() + BASEHT + BASEWID / -7;
        double crRad = BASEWID / 60;
        cr[0] = new Circle(crX1, crY, crRad);
        cr[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cr[0].setFill(Color.FLORALWHITE);

        //house line
        double midX = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID / 2;
        double leftX = bx[0].getX() - BASEWID / 2;
        double rightX = bx[0].getX() + BASEWID + BASEWID / 2;
        double topY = bx[0].getY() - BASEHT / 2;
        double bottomY = bx[0].getY() + BASEHT / 2;
        ln[0] = new Line(midX, topY, leftX, bottomY);
        ln[1] = new Line(midX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

        //top of house
        ply[0] = new Polygon(ln[0].getStartX(),ln[0].getStartY(),
                bx[0].getX(),bx[0].getY(),
                bx[0].getX()+bx[0].getWidth(),bx[0].getY());
        ply[0].getPoints().addAll();
        ply[0].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ply[0].setFill(Color.MEDIUMAQUAMARINE);

        //vertical window panes
        ln[2] = new Line(70, 251, 70, 213);
        ln[3] = new Line(170, 251, 170, 213);
        ln[4] = new Line(70, 133, 70, 172);
        ln[5] = new Line(170, 133, 170, 172);

        //horizontal window panes
        ln[6] = new Line(50, 232, 90, 232);
        ln[7] = new Line(150, 232, 190, 232);
        ln[8] = new Line(50, 152, 90, 152);
        ln[9] = new Line(150, 152, 190, 152); 


        trGrp.getChildren().addAll(bx[0], bx[1], bx[2], bx[3], bx[4], bx[5], cr[0], ply[0], ln[2], ln[3], ln[4], ln[5], ln[6], ln[7], ln[8], ln[9]);
    }

    // Get the X Coordinate
    public double getX()
    {
        return trGrp.getLayoutX();
    }

    // Set the X Coordinate
    public void setX(double x)
    {
        trGrp.setLayoutX(x);
    }

    // Get the Y Coordinate
    public double getY()
    {
        return trGrp.getLayoutY();
    }

    // Set the Y Coordinate
    public void setY(double y)
    {
        trGrp.setLayoutY(y);
    }

}
```